# MongoDB Aggregation w/ Embedded Documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document that I want to split up into multiple documents.

The document looks like this.

```
{
 a:1,
 b:2,
 c:3,
 d:4,
}
{
 a:5,
 b:6
 c:7
 d:8
}
```

I want to pull out "d" into separate documents. I know that `$unwind` would unwind an array, but how would I unwind a situation like this?

```
Document 1
{
 d:4
}

Document 2
{
 d:8
}
```

Comment: what about doing `db.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'd': 1})`?

Comment: Are these separate documents in a collection? Or are these documents members of an array within a document? In the former case you just use basic projection as suggested. In the latter then you would `$project` after an `$unwind`. Seems like the former is the case though without more detail to the example.